# Laravel 5 on CentOS 7 Not Working On Domain

Tags: php, laravel, centos, laravel-5.6

I've installed Laravel 5 on CentOS 7 with ease. Made .htaccess changes and and generated application key. My .conf file is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/laravel/public"
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin x@localhost

    <Directory "/var/www/html/laravel">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when i try to open it via www.mydomain.com it opens Apache Testing 123.. page. And when i try www.mydomain.com/laravel/public, i can see default laravel page.

What am i missing?

Comment: `<Directory "/var/www/html/laravel">` should be `<Directory "/var/www/html/laravel/public">` (it should also have that public directory). Out of curiousity, which version of Apache is included with CentOS 7? 2.2 or 2.4?

Comment: @ChrisForrence Not worked.

Comment: It looks like the `Order allow,deny` and `Allow from all` directives shouldn't be there, because CentOS 7 uses Apache 2.4, and those directives are 2.2-only

Comment: @ChrisForrence I've removed those lines and restart httpd, but nothing changes. Still not working correctly :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/laravel"
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin x@localhost

    <Directory "/var/www/html/laravel">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Directory and document root should be the same

Comment: Still the same. mydomain.com goes to apache test page and mydomain.com/laravel/public goes to laravel.

Comment: I think the answer for this question will be yes, but did you change the /etc/hosts?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem some months ago, check in your .htaccess for the following lines

```
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
```

If it's like this, include index.php so when apache is looking in the public folder it will use that file to redirect your routes. Also be sure you are loading the php module.

```
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
```

Comment: Hi. I think something else causing this problem like from .htaccess or VirtualHost etc.